# Finding the roots of higher degree polynomials by factoring

Tags: polynomials

For instance, consider this polynomial $x^3-3x^2+2x-39270$. I happen to know that $35$ is a root, and thus I can use synthetic division to factor out $(x-35)$. But if I would attempt to find a root using the rational root theorem, I would have too many options, since the constant is such a big number.

Is there a faster and more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: The rational root test is quite fast. Of course, you can use any of the various factorisation algorithms for integer polynomials. In your case, this is still very fast: $f=(x^2 + 32x + 1122)(x - 35)$. But in general, it is not.

Comment: A polynomial of degree $3$ can be solved directly although the formula is quite complicated.

Comment: @Peter Yes, got distracted copying from the book, already edited.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I agree. But if the root happens to be quite large, the direct method could be superior in speed. Imagine an extremely large coefficient. In this case, the factorization would already take some time.

Comment: Yes, indeed. For large integers, the factorisation of integers alone becomes very difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you omitted some context from your question, and $x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x - 39270$ was not made up by you?

The reason I ask is that the zeros of this cubic polynomial can be found by solving $x(x^2 - 3x + 2) = 39270,$ which is equivalent to $x(x-1)(x-2) = 39270,$ and thus one is led to consider the possibility that 39270 is the product of three consecutive integers, each of which is roughly the cube root of 39270.

Since $32^3 = 32 \times 32^2 = 32 \times 2^{10},$ which is approximately $32 \times 1000 = 32000,$ one is led to look for three consecutive integers in the vicinity of $32$ such that their product ends in $0.$ Three possibilities arise, namely $(33)(34)(35)$ and $(34)(35)(36)$ and $(35)(36)(37).$ A quick check shows that $(33)(34)(35) = 39270,$ and thus $x = 35$ is a zero of your cubic polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

If you depress the polynomial (cancel the quadratic term by shifting the variable, $x:=y+1$), you get

$$y^3-y-39270=0.$$

If you assume that $y^3\gg y$ and neglect $y$, $y^3=39270$ yields $y=33.99\cdots$, and searching nearby integer solutions you immediately get

$$34^3-34=29270.$$

This will work whenever the solution is known to be integer and the linear coefficient is small.